# Google Maps are not showing in Jaspersoft Reports Studio

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have an issue using TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio regarding Google maps.

I am using "map" component provided by Jasper Studio, and I have done all necessary configurations as described in User Manual:

> To configure a property, click Add to open the Properties dialog,
>   enter the name of the property and the property's value, then click
>   OK. You can configure the following Google Maps APIs properties. See
>   the JasperReports® Library configuration reference for more
>   information on each property: •
>   **net.sf.jasperreports.components.map.client.id** – Specifies the client
>   ID for Google Maps API for Business. If set, it takes precedence over
>   the API key property. Usually works along with the signature property
>   for signed URLs. • **net.sf.jasperreports.components.map.key** – Specifies
>   the Google Maps API key. •
>   **net.sf.jasperreports.components.map.signature** – Specifies the
>   encrypted client signature for signed request URLs. •
>   **net.sf.jasperreports.components.map.version** – Indicates which version
>   of the Google Maps API should be loaded.

I have added my Google maps API key as stated.

But when I try to run report preview, Jasper Studio freezes, and after some time I received message as in following image:

[image: Message box with details of error]

Should I adjust something in my Google Maps Console or what? This API key is valid, as I use it in my application.

Comment: If you pass the url (with key) as indicated in error into a browser, what do you get?

Comment: Ok, this is what I get: The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'size' parameter. https://imgur.com/a/wZcGXV4

Comment: I found the problem. '&' is missing between parameters in URL, but I don't know why Jaspersoft studio is not showing it in url (url is generated by Jaspersoft studio). PS. There are '&' in Details section of error window, but not in link for Reason. (look at the image in Question)

Comment: Also, I've noticed '.' at the end of url?! That's is also something that shouldn't be there since it makes API invalid.

Comment: You need to type the url in the stacktrace, in your image it's at the bottom

Comment: Have you enabled billing for your api key?

Comment: @PetterFriberg I did what you said, and when I type URL in browser, map is shown. But inside of Jasperstudio it doesn't work. Billing is enabled.

Comment: hmm interesting have you tried when exporting (not from jasper-reports preview), it looks like it can not get the image data for some reason (maybe security reason)

Comment: Maybe, we have found something. It works when I use HTML option, but not with PDF or Java preview. Previously I removed API Application restrictions in my Google Console. What kind of Maps API I should enable/use: Maps JavaScript API, Maps Static API or Maps Embed API?

Comment: Maps Static Api, it's creating an image. It should not be different generating html or pdf, but I would need to check the source code to verify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I asked our server administrator to send me once more logs from our Jasper server, and I found this:

`2019-02-11 14:41:38,353 ERROR ErrorPageHandlerAction,http-nio-8080-exec-8:118 - Error UID 21b6e730-143b-47bb-b792-cde9b48db610
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report
...
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Invalid coordinates geocoded from address; latitude: latitude; longitude: longitude.
    ....`

I was puzzled how I get "Invalid coordinates geocoded from address; latitude: latitude; longitude: longitude." when it is okay for HTML and not for Java or PDF.

I switched on/off several API's (Geolocation API, Geocoding API) in my Google Cloud Platform. After few minutes, maps started working in every option needed (Java, PDF, HTML)

It has no sense to me, but maps are working now.

APIs that I use are: Maps JavaScript API, Maps Static API